# Как использовать $_SESSION для определённых посетителей сайта?

Tags: сессия, php

**Здравствуйте!**

Есть сайт, в нём на странице **contacts.php** и в **"подвале"** (подвал подключён на страницах через INCLUDE) сайта на каждой странице указаны определённые номера телефонов.

**Задача в том, чтобы** при переходе на сайт с внешней ссылки с определённой переменной GET (например: http://site.ru/page.php?my=1) в **contacts.php** и "подвале" сайта менялись номера телефонов.

Я предположил, что это возможно реализовать при помощи механизма **СЕССИЙ ($_SESSION)**, с данным механизмом пытался разобраться и применить, но всё безуспешно, не могу догнать логику.

**Подскажите какой-нибудь пример как это реализовать** если это возможно, или какой либо источник по сессиям (уроки, книги и т.д.) **если конечно я на правильном пути!**

**СПАСИБО!**

Comment: Подробнее напишет кто-нибудь другой, но общий ход такой:
0) Включаем механизм сессий (session_start()).
1) Проверяем наличие параметра GET.
2) Если параметр найден, то записываем этот факт в сессию.
3) В футере проверяем сессию и параметр GET (если сессия пишется в самом-самом конце), если находим нужное условие и меняем телефоны.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если смена номеров происходит в зависимости от реферера то предложу Вам такой алгоритм:
В index.php в самом верху прописываем старт сессии:

```
session_start();
```

Сразу же после неё:

```
// Проверяем не перешли ли к нам с  сайтов, требуемых для смены телефонов:
if($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://site.ru/page.php?my=1'){
    $_SESSION['phone'] = 1;
}
elseif($_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER'] == 'http://site2.ru/page.php?my=1'){
    $_SESSION['phone'] = 2;
};
```

После чего там где требуется вставить телефон вставляем примерно такую конструкцию:

```
if(isset($_SESSION['phone'])){
    // Если существует сесионная переменная проверяем её значение и вставляем соответствующий телефон(ы)
    switch($_SESSION['phone']){
        case'1':
            echo $phone1;
        break;
        case'2':
            echo $phone1;
        break;
    }
}
else{
    // Если сесионная переменная не была создана то вставляем телефон(ы) назначеные по умолчанию.
    echo $defaultPhone;
};
```

Как то так.

Comment: Попробовал, выдаёт следующее:
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent

Comment: неудивительно, сессию нужно стартовать *до* любого вывода

Comment: Согласен, убрал подпись BOM, всё отлично, только станицу выводит на кракозябрах, почему-то ставит Кодировку - Кирилица

Comment: сменил кодировку на веб-сервере, всё отлично! Всем спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Если у каждой ссылки есть свой **GET**, то зачем вам "**сессия**"?
**Сессия** довольно ресурсоёмкий процесс.

Создайте  ***массив*** с номерами телефона (если конечно не тянете с БД) и ***переменную*** (для вывода телефона) и разместите её в ***contacts.php*** и в ***подвале***.

К примеру:

```
$arr = array("79161234561","79161234562","79161234563");
//http://site.ru?id=1
if(isset($_GET[id])){ 
    $id=$_GET[id];
    $tel = $arr[$id]; //получаем 79161234562
}
//размещаем переменную $tel в contacts.php и подвале
```

Answer (score 0):

Добрый вечер. А зачем тут, собственно сессии?

**page.php**

```
$my_val=$_GET['my'];
include('contacts.php');
```

**contacts.php**

```
<?php
if($my_val==1){
echo "такой вот номер телефона";
}else{
echo "нет, ты не свой, на тебе такой вот номер телефона";
}
?>
```

про сессии: [вот](http://www.codenet.ru/webmast/php/PHP-Sessions.php) ссылка, но только вот использовать echo, как там показано, нес стоит :)